# mkdir path error - Trying to concatenate strings

Tags: powershell, syntax, concatenation, mkdir

I am trying to just make a directory, but I cannot figure it out. I am trying to make a template so I want everything in the program to reference the form name. I am using Powershell Studio to write this program.

This does not work (Desired method):

```
$FormName = $formChangeMe.Text | out-string
$PATHDIR = ($env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Local\Tools\" + $FormName)
md -Force $PATHDIR
```

Output from `$PATHDIR` returns `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Tools\ChangeMe` but it wont make the directory.

This does work:

```
$PATHDIR = "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Tools\ChangeMe"
md -Force $PATHDIR
```

I cant see why the one works and the other doesn't. I don't think I understand when to use `()` vs `''` vs `""`.

Comment: Compare `$PATHDIR.Length` in both cases.

Comment: Like PetSerAl says... there might be some extra characters hidden there. `$FormName = ($formChangeMe.Text | out-string).Trim()`?

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Make it as an answer and ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$FormName = ($formChangeMe.Text | out-string).Trim()` - Thanks to Matt!!